# Eclipse: Renaming an output file after running the run configuration

Tags: eclipse, maven, triggers, scripting, rename

I have an eclipse project(a) that i build using maven using a run configuration which results in an x.jar file being created. Is there any way i could run another rename script that would be triggered after x.jar is built.

So the workflow would be a ->(Trigger Run Configuration) Builds a -> Gives x.jar -> On execution of Run configuration, trigger the rename script -> x.jar renamed to ax.jar.

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/examples/post-build-script.html

Answer (score 0):

You could define the desired name of your jar using the finalName element in your Maven build configuration.  See https://maven.apache.org/pom.html.  By default, the finalName will be artifactId-version, and the extension will be determined by the project packaging element.

If you want to change that, you could just add something like this to the build element of your pom:

```
 <build>
...
    <finalName>ax</finalName>
...
```